# Converting matrix into scatterplot

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have a matrix which look like that:

```
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
name1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
name2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
name3 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
name4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

And I would like to make a kind of scatter plot with i.e. red point when there is '1', green point when there is '2' and nothing when '0'. Name* are rownames. How can I do that?
I want to replace heatmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the plotting:

```
plot(which(d==1, arr.ind=TRUE)[,'col'], which(d==1,arr.ind=TRUE)[,'row'], col="red", 
    xlim=c(1,ncol(d)), ylim=rev(c(1,nrow(d))))
points(which(d==2, arr.ind=TRUE)[,'col'], which(d==2,arr.ind=TRUE)[,'row'], col="green")
```

You can set the row and column numbers explicitly if you don't like the default behavior:

```
plot(which(d==1,arr.ind=TRUE)[,'col'], which(d==1,arr.ind=TRUE)[,'row'], col="red", 
    xlim=c(1,ncol(d)), ylim=rev(c(1,nrow(d))), xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
points(which(d==2,arr.ind=TRUE)[,'col'], which(d==2,arr.ind=TRUE)[,'row'], col="green")
axis(1, at = seq(1, 9, by = 1))
axis(2, at = seq(1, 4, by = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a ggplot2 solution.

```
x = "0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
     1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
     0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"

df = (t(matrix(scan(text= x), nrow = 9)))
library(reshape2)
df = melt(d[c(4:1),])

ggplot(df[df$value!=0,], aes(y = X1, x = X2)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(value)), size = 10) +
  scale_color_manual(name="", values = c("red", "green")) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = paste(rep("name", 4), 1:4)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:8) +
  theme_bw() + xlab("") + ylab("")
```

[image: ggplot2 solution]

Comment: What if I have a lot of variables 'name' on y-axis? If I use scale_y_continuous I get an error '  Breaks and labels are different lengths' but when I use scale_y_discrete not all 'names' display on the plot.

Comment: You need to change both 4s here `paste(rep("name", 4), 1:4))` to the actual number of names you have. And since Frank mentioned that the y-label is flipped. Do this instead `rev(paste(rep("name", n), 1:n)))`